# Can we give different colors to buttons shown on alert box through DisplayAlert() method, in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can we give different colors to buttons shown on alert box through DisplayAlert() method, in Xamarin.Forms?

I can find its solution in android but I am unable to get in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. With `DisplayActionSheet`, you could only use one "Destructive" action which will be red on most of OSes.

You could write a custom version of alert box though. Here it's nice codebase for this: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Comment: The question is likely about Xamarin.Forms, where such customization is probably really really hard.

Comment: ACR User Dialogs is Xamarin.Forms compatibile and it's possible to edit it's source code to handle button colors (but it's platform specific).